# How to make dynamic image view?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

[image]

There is a static image view (in reference image) but i would like to make it dynamic.

How can it be possible?

Comment: Can you please make your question clearer? It's hard to understand what you need. If possible add some example code.

Comment: What do you mean by "Dynamic image"?

Comment: I want to make image Gallery as like any  Photo viewer Software

Comment: Add more details. Here is a tutorial about creating gallery on ios, but I'm not sure that it's what you are looking for: http://cases.azoft.com/creating-image-gallery-ios-apps-uiimageview/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return arrThemeImage.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString *identifier=@"Cell";
[collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
UICollectionViewCell *cell;

cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *imgViewTheme=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 101, 101)];
NSString *strThemeImg=arrThemeImage[indexPath.row];
imgViewTheme.image=[UIImage imageNamed:strThemeImg];

[cell.contentView addSubview:imgViewTheme];


return cell;
 }
```

Use collection view, and don't forget to map delegate and datasource.

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill; //?
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use UICollectionView. Please see the [Apple Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html).

These tutorial might be helpful for you.

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/

http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

UICollection View is best solution for you !!!!

you may follow the links below it will help you

http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12
http://www.raywenderlich.com/22417/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-22